# $.ajax do not work in blackberry10 phonegap but works in android phonegap

Tags: ajax, cordova

```
$.ajax({ 
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://'localhost'/Health/appointment?DoctorName=" + u + "&Password=" + p + "&dbversion=1.3",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",                               
        success: function (msg) {
             //alert("in success: " + JSON.stringify(msg) + " " + msg.flag + " " + msg.UserID + " " + msg.DoctorId);
            window.location.href = 'option.html?UserID=' + msg.UserID + '&DoctorId=' + msg.DoctorId;

        },error: function(response) {
            alert("in Error");
        }               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
dataType: json
instead of jsonp